# Find $\sigma_1$ that minimizes $(e^{x^2/\sigma_1^2}e^{x^2/\sigma_2^2}-e^{x^2/\sigma_3^2})^2$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to find

\begin{equation}
\arg\min_{\sigma_1} \left(\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma_1^2}\right)\cdot \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma_2^2}\right)-\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma_3^2}\right)\right)^2
\end{equation}

for real $x,\sigma_i$. In other words, multiplying one Gaussian by another in order to best approximate a third.

Mathematica reports that there is no global minimum for this expression. I'm wondering if there's some way of conditioning quantities, some trick with logs I don't know about, etc. to arrive at a useful characterization.

Comment: Do you expect the entire expression to be positive or it does not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

If

$$
e^{x^2/\sigma_1^2}e^{x^2/\sigma_2^2}=e^{x^2/\sigma_3^2}
$$

then

$$
e^{x^2/\sigma_1^2} = e^{x^2/\sigma_3^2-x^2/\sigma_2^2}
$$

or

$$
\frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} = \frac{1}{\sigma_3^2}-\frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}
$$

of course if $\sigma_3 < \sigma_2$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cesareo, that's simple enough. So the solution is then

\begin{equation}
    \sigma_1 = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        \infty, & \text{for } \sigma_3\geq \sigma_2\\
        \frac{\sigma_3\sigma_2}{\sqrt{\sigma_2^2-\sigma_3^2}}, & \text{for } \sigma_3< \sigma_2\\
        \end{array}\right\}
\end{equation}